Generating Random Numbers using Rising and Falling Exponential Function
I am working with this normalized pdf,
$$
f(t) = (\tau_d - \tau_r)^{-1}(-e^{-t/\tau_r} + e^{-t/\tau_d}),~~t \geq0
$$
And $\tau_d > \tau_r$.
Are there any methods for generating random values $t \sim f(t)$? The CDF cannot be computed exactly due to the addition of two exponentials. I've tried using approximate methods such as those available in scipy (here) but they struggle with the long tail of the pdf.
